# Loop without Do error but Do is there

Tags: vba, excel, loops

The following code gives a Loop without Do Compile error:

```
Loop
    Sheets("Snap").Rows(1).AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=List
    Sheets("Snap").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy _
        Destination:=LastCell
    Sheets("RAW").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = "+"
    Set List = List.Offset(1, 0)
If IsEmpty(List) Then
    Exit Do
End If
Do
```

But as you can see the Do is present so I have no idea why is this giving me an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Do While ... Loop is backwards.

```
do while true
    Sheets("Snap").Rows(1).AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=List
    Sheets("Snap").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy _
        Destination:=LastCell
    Sheets("RAW").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = "+"
    Set List = List.Offset(1, 0)
    If IsEmpty(List) Then
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop
```

Alternately,

```
do while not IsEmpty(List)
    Sheets("Snap").Rows(1).AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=List
    Sheets("Snap").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy _
        Destination:=LastCell
    Sheets("RAW").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = "+"
    Set List = List.Offset(1, 0)
Loop
```

Comment: Makes sense, thank you! Is there any difference between the 2? The second one looks better to me and more easy to read.

Comment: No functional difference between the two except that the first will enter the loop even if List starts off empty; the second will not.